# SublimeText 3's PHP syntax behaving like HTML syntax (for comments)

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I'm editing a saved .php file in Sublime Text 3 (build 3126 for mac), and when I try to comment something out using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, Sublime inserts the standard HTML comment

```
<!-- -->
```

Sublime does not comment out when I try to use DocBlocks, /* */, # or //.

I've checked and Sublime is currently set to PHP syntax, as it should be. The Build System is set to Automatic. Has anyone ever experienced this and do you know of a fix? I couldn't find this problem anywhere on StackExchange and the only thing I found on Google was:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/cant-set-syntax-to-php/7478/8

Since their symptoms don't exactly match mine, I thought I'd ask here before I go as far as clearing caches that I don't know much about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this answer is too simple, but it might be your case:

In SublimeText3 when opening comments using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>:

1. When editing brand-new empty saved .php file, sublime use HTML comments   `<\!-- -->`
2. But when you open a PHP tag, AND your cursor is inside it, Sublime uses right PHP comments `/* */` or `//`

So it's context sensitive. It uses PHP comments only inside PHP code fragments.

*Remember that PHP opening tag is required even in pure PHP-code files.*

Comment: *DOH* You are correct. I was trying to add a comment before my opening php tag at the very beginning of the document. Although I could have sworn I tried multiple times to comment out within the PHP code as well...I did change the Build System to python, then back to automatic. So it was either that, or your suggestion which fixed things. Either way, I lean toward it being a brain fart on my end and your answer being the fix. You are definitely correct about not being able to use PHP comments outside of PHP tags (even within a PHP file), and I didn't know that. Thanks for your help!